# How to display results from only select subgroups + the whole data frame in an expss table?

Tags: r, expss

Apologies for what is a pretty basic question... I am loving using the **expss** package for table creation, but am having trouble working through some of the output display. Specifically, I have a situation where my data frame contains a grouping variable as well as a few variables that will be summarized. I'd like to create output that displays certain summary statistics for each value of the subgroup *in turn* (each value of the grouping variable) plus the total for the whole sample.  Something like the code below, but appending the `output1` and `output2` objects together in a single table that maintains the formatting of **expss**'s RStudio Viewer output.

```
library(expss)

set.seed(12345)

df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:5, each = 4),
                 varA = sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 varB = sample(6:9, 20, replace = TRUE))

output1 <- df[df$group == 1, ] %>%
  tab_cells(varA, varB) %>%
  tab_cols(total(label = "")) %>% 
  tab_stat_fun("Valid N" = w_n, "Mean" = w_mean, "SD" = w_sd,
               "Median" = w_median, method = list) %>% 
  tab_pivot() %>% 
  set_caption("Group 1")

output2 <- df %>%
  tab_cells(varA, varB) %>%
  tab_cols(total(label = "")) %>% 
  tab_stat_fun("Valid N" = w_n, "Mean" = w_mean, "SD" = w_sd,
               "Median" = w_median, method = list) %>% 
  tab_pivot() %>% 
  set_caption("All Groups")

expss_output_viewer()

output1
output2
```

I know that I can add `tab_rows(group)` to the piping which will display all of the groups; however, I am only interested in displaying each group in turn (plus the total), *not* all groups, for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are special function for subgroups: `tab_subgroup`:

```
library(expss)

set.seed(12345)

df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:5, each = 4),
                 varA = sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 varB = sample(6:9, 20, replace = TRUE))

output <- df %>%
    tab_cells(varA, varB) %>%
    tab_cols(total(label = "")) %>% 
    tab_subgroup(group == 1) %>% 
    tab_row_label("Group 1") %>% 
    tab_stat_fun("Valid N" = w_n, "Mean" = w_mean, "SD" = w_sd,
                 "Median" = w_median, method = list) %>% 
    tab_row_label("All Groups") %>% 
    tab_subgroup() %>% 
    tab_stat_fun("Valid N" = w_n, "Mean" = w_mean, "SD" = w_sd,
                 "Median" = w_median, method = list) %>% 
    tab_pivot()

expss_output_viewer()

output
```

Alternatively, you can use `tab_rows` and `net`:

```
library(expss)

set.seed(12345)

df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:5, each = 4),
                 varA = sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 varB = sample(6:9, 20, replace = TRUE))
output <- df %>%
    tab_cells(varA, varB) %>%
    tab_cols(total(label = "")) %>% 
    tab_rows(net(group, "Group 1" = 1,  "All Groups" = 1:5, position = "above")) %>%
    tab_stat_fun("Valid N" = w_n, "Mean" = w_mean, "SD" = w_sd,
                 "Median" = w_median, method = list) %>% 
    tab_pivot()

expss_output_viewer()

output
```